# Rx: How to buffer items until condition is met

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a stream of items and I want to buffer them until one of the items meets a condition. Once the condition is met, the buffered items should be delivered to the subscriber.

If the source observable completes but the condition hasn't been met yet, I want an error to be produced.

Can this be achieved using default operators in RxJava or another language of the Rx family?

Comment: You could introduce a subject to get the behaviour, is that acceptable?

Comment: Every solution that works is acceptable, however I'm not very familiar with subjects.

Answer (score 1):

I've written the example below using [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) simply so that we can run the example here live. The concepts are identical to RxJava.

A `BufferedSubject`:

```js
class BufferedSubject extends Rx.Subject {
    constructor(predicate) {
        super();
        this.predicate = predicate;
        this.buffer = [];
        this.unbuffered = false;
    }

    onNext(e) {
        if (this.unbuffered) {
            super.onNext(e);
            return;
        }

        if (this.predicate(e)) {
            while (this.buffer.length) {
                super.onNext(this.buffer.shift());
            }

            super.onNext(e);
            this.unbuffered = true;
            return;
        }

        this.buffer.push(e);
    }
}
```

You can use a `BufferedSubject` as you would a regular subject, as a intermediary between some source observable and your desired buffered observable—you subscribe to the subject and the subject subscribes to the source observable, with the subject maintaining a buffer of the items until some condition holds true. By example:

```js
const timer = Rx.Observable.interval(5000);
const subject = new BufferedSubject((item) => item > 5);
subject.subscribe(
    x => $('.list').append(`<li>${x} seconds</li>`)
);
timer.subscribe(subject);
```

As a runnable snippet (compiled from ES6, sorry):

```js
'use strict';
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
    if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function');
    }
}
function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) {
    if (!self) {
        throw new ReferenceError('this hasn\'t been initialised - super() hasn\'t been called');
    }
    return call && (typeof call === 'object' || typeof call === 'function') ? call : self;
}
function _inherits(subClass, superClass) {
    if (typeof superClass !== 'function' && superClass !== null) {
        throw new TypeError('Super expression must either be null or a function, not ' + typeof superClass);
    }
    subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: subClass,
            enumerable: false,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });
    if (superClass)
        Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
}
var BufferedSubject = function (_Rx$Subject) {
    _inherits(BufferedSubject, _Rx$Subject);
    function BufferedSubject(predicate) {
        _classCallCheck(this, BufferedSubject);
        var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _Rx$Subject.call(this));
        _this.predicate = predicate;
        _this.buffer = [];
        _this.unbuffered = false;
        return _this;
    }
    BufferedSubject.prototype.onNext = function onNext(e) {
        if (this.unbuffered) {
            _Rx$Subject.prototype.onNext.call(this, e);
            return;
        }
        if (this.predicate(e)) {
            while (this.buffer.length) {
                _Rx$Subject.prototype.onNext.call(this, this.buffer.shift());
            }
            _Rx$Subject.prototype.onNext.call(this, e);
            this.unbuffered = true;
            return;
        }
        this.buffer.push(e);
    };
    return BufferedSubject;
}(Rx.Subject);
var timer = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).skip(1).take(50).publish();
var subject = new BufferedSubject(function (item) {
    return item > 5;
});
subject.subscribe(function (x) {
    return $('.list').append('<li>' + x + ' seconds</li>');
}, function (e) {
    return $('.list').append('<li>Errror ' + e + '</li>');
}, function (_) {
    return $('.list').append('<li>Sequence complete</li>');
});
timer.subscribe(subject);
timer.subscribe(function (x) {
    return $('.timer').text(x + ' seconds elapsed');
});
timer.connect();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.7/rx.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Output (<span class='timer'>-</span>):</p>

<ul class="list">
</ul>
```

(Also available on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/whymarrh/pen/wMRONW).)

Note: I'd say that this implementation does not support backpressure correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your solution, every element after the one fulfilling the predicate would also need to fulfill the predicate. What I was loooking for was a single item fulfilling the predicate, after that nothing should ever be buffered. However, adapting your code wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Good catch, I've fixed that!